# Nested Lists with different lengths into dataframe

Tags: r

I am using R and the package mongolite to get data from a MongoDB. This results in data consisting of lots of nested lists that cannot be simplified into a data frame by using unlist, rbindlist, nor bind_rows from dplyr (at least I did not manage to do it).

After a lot of trial and error I found a way to do it using the package reshape2 with the function melt and using dplyr and tidyr to get it into the form I want it to be. However, the melting takes a lot of time (up to 15 mins per list, and I have 6 of them).

Do you have any ideas how I can make this faster? (Of course another possible solution would be to query the MongoDB correctly such that it does not result in lists but in something more like my target data frame).

The following code creates a dummy dataset with similar attributes, the target form of the dataset and my solution to get there.

**Dummy Data:**

```
dummy_data <- list(
  list(actions = list(list(action_type = "link_clicks", value = 30), 
                      list(action_type = "post_likes", value = 3)), 
       date = '2015-08-04'), 
  list(actions = list(list(action_type = "link_clicks", value = 10), 
                      list(action_type = "post_likes", value = 2),
                      list(action_type = "page_engagement", value = 5)), 
       date = '2015-08-02')
  )
```

**Target Form:**

```
final_data = data.frame(c(30, 10), c(3, 2), c(NA, 5), c('2015-08-04', '2015-08-02'))
names(final_data) = c('actions: link_clicks', 'actions: post_likes', 'actions: page_engagement', 'date')
final_data
```

**Temporary solution**

```
Solution <- reshape2::melt(dummy_data)
Solution <- Solution %>% 
  select(L1, L2, L3, L4, value) %>%
  mutate(L4 = ifelse(is.na(L4), L2, L4)) %>% 
  spread(key = L4, value = value) %>%
  mutate(L2 = ifelse(!is.na(action_type), paste0(L2, ": ", action_type), L2),
         value = ifelse(!is.na(value), value, date)) %>%
  select(L1, L2, value) %>%
  spread(key = L2, value = value) %>% 
  select(-L1)
```

If you have any advice on the mongolite query here is the simplest kind of queries I use:

```
M_DB <- mongolite::mongo(collection = "name", url = "url")
M_DB_List <- M_DB$iterate()$batch(size = 100000)
```

Thanks a lot

**Edit: **
A more complex data structure as this is closer to my problem

```
 dummy_data_complex <- list(
  list(actions = list(list(action_type = "link_clicks", value = 30), 
                      list(action_type = "post_likes", value = 3)), 
       date = '2015-08-04',
       currency = 'EUR'), 
  list(actions = list(list(action_type = "link_clicks", value = 10), 
                      list(action_type = "post_likes", value = 2),
                      list(action_type = "page_engagement", value = 5)), 
       date = '2015-08-02',
       demographics = list(gender = "female", 
                           list(actions = list(action_type = "link_clicks", value = 10)))
  ))
```

Comment: You are right. I separated it into two data sets now - hope thats better and thanks for your help

Comment: I recommend writing an `aggregation` query directly in `mongodb`. Maybe you should ask a new question, giving an example of your data in mongo, and the structure of the data you want out of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
dummy_data %>% 
     map_df(~ .x %>%
                 as_tibble(.) %>%
                 mutate(actions = map(actions, as_tibble)) %>%
                          unnest)   %>%
     group_by(date, action_type) %>%
     mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
     spread(action_type, value) %>%
     select(-n)
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups: date [2]
#   date       link_clicks page_engagement post_likes
#* <chr>            <dbl>           <dbl>      <dbl>
#1 2015-08-02        10.0            5.00       2.00
#2 2015-08-04        30.0           NA          3.00
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, unfortunately my real data has a lot of lower level lists inside like the actions part. Would I then have to specifically map each of those?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a fast solution for my problem. 
It was solved by using another query as SymbolixAU suggested.

Instead of using iterate() I used find() which then resulted in a dataframe with nested lists inside it.

From this point on I was easily able to get to my target using tidyr::unnest()

Thanks for your help.